# Map Fn Key as Ctrl on a Late 2007 MacBook 3,1 running latest Linux Mint

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, fn-key

I have a Late 2007 MacBook 3,1 and on those computers the Fn key is at the leftmost position. It is extremely annoying when using shortcuts. I can't even get used to it because I work with other computers as well.

It runs Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa.

**xev** finds no event for the Fn key but **evtest** returns :

> Event: time 1564351034.631624, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 464 (KEY_FN), value 0

Can I swap Fn and Ctrl ? How do I do ?

Comment: Macs don't use the EFI like that. Also, Fn is mapped before it even leaves the keyboard. It doesn't generate any key code of its own.

Comment: @Tetsujin Do you mean it's impossible ?

Comment: afaik, correct, can't be done. Someone may know better, so don't give up hope, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements). It has a lot of options to modify you keyboard, and swapping Fn and Ctrl is one of them.

I am using it on my MacBook.

For details see the [documentation](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html).

AFAIK, you can use neither EFI nor BIOS to do such remapping, not on a MacBook, and not on a PC-style laptop, either.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a old MacBook and I run Linux Mint 19.1 on it. (And it works fine)

Comment: Please edit your question and mention that you are running Linux Mint on it, this is important information and changes the whole question drastically. Because now the important point is how Linux receives the `Fn` key event. So run `evtest`, figure out  the right device for your keyboard, and edit the question with the result of pressing the `Fn` key. If nothing appears, the `Fn` key is likely handled via the EC, which will make things really difficult.